# Multithreaded update of DataTable in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, oracle, datatable

Have looked for an answer here, but couldn't find one.

When you call:

```
myTableAdapter.Update(myDataTable);
```

.NET will process the rows one at a time and perform insert, update, or delete commands, which ever is appropriate for the row.

Does this happen in a multi-threaded fashion?  My guess is no, and if not, I will have to look into ways I can do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that I can say with certainty that it is NOT multi-threaded.  Not only is there no mention of such in the doc, but it could introduce unreliable behavior, since rows would not be updated in the order in which they appear in the datatable.

Comment: I wouldn't think the order in which they're updated would matter... there are no self-referencing fields.  What would be your concern there?

Comment: It is certainly possible for a table to have a column that is a foreign key to the same table, in which case order of insertion matters.  Example: items on a food menu, where one item "goes with" another, e.g., butter with toast. So the toast row must be inserted before the butter row, as the latter references the former.

Comment: Sure, sorry... I was thinking of my specific situation, you meant that's why it isn't handled in general.  Which of course makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

No its not multihreaded. That would require opening up a separate connection for each thread it would create which typically is very undesirable.

Comment: My expectation would be that connection pooling would manage that... would you agree?  I would have to limit the number of threads to at most the max number of connections in the pool, of course, or the threads would pile up waiting for a connection to free up.

Comment: @JamesB that would allow a single logical action (update) to consume all the connections in a pool. It would also allow for the greater consumption of database resources. You'd also have to deal with the potential that some of the connection.opens will succeed while others fail. These problems violate the principle of least surprise. In other words this may be what *you* want but not what your typical developer would expect from `Adapter.Update`

Comment: Plus, transactions do not (usually) cross connections, so you'd lose transactional atomicity.